# Why typedef can not be used with static?

Tags: c++

Why typedef can not be used with static? For example, the code below is an error

```
typedef static int INT2;
```

What other rules should be follow to use the typedef? What other keywords can not be used with typedef?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Both typedef and static are storage classes in the language (strictly true for C; I believe it is also true for C++).  You can only have one storage class in a single declaration - you have two in your example, hence the error.

Comment: +1. "The typedef specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class specifier’’ for syntactic convenience only;"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

typedef doesn't declare an *instance* of a variable, it declares a type (type alias actually),

`static` is a qualifier you apply to an instance, not a type, so you can use static when you *use* the type, but not when you define the type. Like this..

```
typedef int int32;
static int32 foo;
```

Comment: `static` is not a qualifier, but a *storage class specifier*. Therefore, it isn't "part of the type" like qualifiers such as `const`, e.g. `typedef const int ci; ci x = 42;` (types with different qualifiers are still the same types, but might not be compatible).

Comment: @John Knoeller
Elegant!
A great Answer!

Answer (score 22):

The `static` keyword is not part of the type, depending on the context it is a storage or scope specifier and has no influence whatsoever on the type.  Therefore, it cannot be used as part of the type definition, which is why it is invalid here.

A typedef is a type definition, i.e. you're saying 'this name' now refers to 'this type', the name you give must be an identifier as defined by the language standard, the type has to be a type specifier, i.e. an already named type, either base type or typedef'd, a struct, union, class, or enum specifier, with possible type qualifiers, i.e. const, or volatile.

The static keyword however does not change the type, it says something about the object, (in general, not in the OOP sense.) e.g. it is the variable that is placed in static storage, not the type.

It looks like you're trying to use a typedef as a macro, i.e.

```
#define MYINT static int
```

Comment: @the Douglas Adams fan: I think it does; perhaps not as clearly as Bailey's answer. Storage specifiers and scope specifiers are not parts of the *type* of something; they're parts of how instances of the type are stored or scoped.

Comment: @Robert well, as the keyword says, it's a type defition, since static is not part of the type, if can't be used in the definition of a type.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: The original answer wasn't this explanatory.

Comment: @dirk the original answer was as you saw it when T.J. made the comment

Answer (score 7):

Storage duration is associated with objects. A typedef declaration creates an alias -- a new name for a type. It does not create objects. Hence you cannot use a storage specifier with a typedef.

Answer (score 5):

`typedef` cannot be used along with `static` as both `typedef` and `static` are storage classes. If you define a variable as `typedef static int a;` then there exist multiple storage classes for the variable `a`.

Storage classes are used to define the scope (visibility) and life-time of variables and/or functions. Some examples are `static`, `auto`, `register`, `extern`, `typedef` etc.

Comment: This is interesting! Indeed, `typedef` is specified as a *storage-class-specifier*, although "for syntactic convenience only" 6.7.1/3.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler said about the same in a [comment to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218435/why-typedef-can-not-be-used-with-static#comment2172109_2218435).

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers from wich and Bailey are correct and enough, but to help clarify to those that commented: When you declare a typedef the resulting type must be consistent everywhere it can be used. What if the typedef you created appears in the following code:

```
INT2 myfunction()
{
  return 0;
}

class MyClass
{
  public: INT2 x;
};

INT2 MyClass::x;
```

- The function returning INT2 would make no sense. Of course the return value is not static (it can't be).
- The x member declaration in MyClass would be static, and also its later definition? That's not only redundant, is incorrect, because you don't use the static keyword when defining a static member - only when declaring it.

The same applies to the other keywords mentioned by Bailey. Think about it: the only keywords that can declare consistently a type for all its uses are the primitive types themselves, and the type modifiers (const, unsigned, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

As many other people have mentioned, `static` is a storage class specifier, not a type.  What this means, specifically, is that the `static` keyword tells tells the compiler something about where a variable should be placed, whether or not it should appear as a symbol for external linking, or how long the variable should remain in existence.

A type is an interpretation of a memory location.  It's a description of what kind of data lives in that location and comes associated with a set of operations that can be performed on that data.

So type and storage class are only related in that they both say something about a piece of data.  The `typedef` keyword is for creating new names for types.

As for a random analogy...

A type is like talking about a specific make and model of car.

A storage class is like saying that a car is stored in a private heated garage and only used on a private racetrack.

A typedef is a nickname for a specific make and model.