# Is typedef a storage-class-specifier?

Tags: c, typedef

I tried the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef static int sint;
    sint i = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

and hit the following error:

```
error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers
```

When I referred the C99 specification, I came to know that `typedef` is a `storage class`.

```
6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers

Syntax

storage-class-specifier:
    typedef
    extern
    static
    auto
    register

Constraints: At most, one storage-class specifier may be 
             given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration

Semantics: The typedef specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class specifier’’ 
           for syntactic convenience only;
```

The only explanation that I could find (based on some internet search and cross referring various sections in C99 specification) was `syntactic convenience only to make the grammar simpler`.

I'm looking for some justification/explanation on how can a type name have storage class specifier?

Doesn't it make sense to have a code like `typedef static int sint;`?

or Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, `typedef` is a storage-class-specifier as you found in the standard. In part it's a grammatical convenience, but it is deliberate that you can either have `typedef` *or* one of the more "obvious" storage class specifiers.

A typedef declaration creates an alias for a type.

In a declaration `static int x;` the type of `x` is `int`. `static` has nothing to do with the type.

(Consider that if you take the address of `x`, `&x` has type `int*`. `int *y = &x;` would be legal as would `static int *z = &x` but this latter `static` affects the storage class of `z` and is independent of the storage class of `x`.)

If something like this were allowed the `static` would have no effect as no object is being declared. The type being aliased is just `int`.

```
typedef static int sint;
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218435/why-typedef-can-not-be-used-with-static

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the standard should have called these things `storage-class-or-typedef-specifier` and said:

> Constraints: At most, one storage-classor-typedef-specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration

Then they wouldn't have had to added the note about the semantics.

The comment about the semantics is simply saying that `typedef` doesn't actually control anything about the storage used for the type (so it isn't semantically a 'storage specifier'), but that it is handled syntactically like the other `storage-class-specifier`, and therefore cannot be used with them.

So a `typedef` can't determine where a particular instance of type will be stored - that's determined by the actual declaration of the instance (either implicitly or explicitly).

Even if what you're looking for were permitted, it would be bad practice, I'm sure. Consider:

```
// in someheader.h
typedef static int sint;


// now in foo.c
#include "someheader.h"

int foo(void)
{
    sint i = 10;   // unless you're intimately knowledgeable about how 
                   //    `sint` is typedef'ed, this looks exactly like
                   //    an automatic


    // do some stuff that modifies `i`...

    return i;
}

sint bar(void)    // what does this mean?  is `bar()` static?
{
    return foo();
}
```

Note that is you use the preprocessor to get the 'static typedef' effect, that would make `bar()` a static function.  Which might not be the effect you want. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that -- at least not with MinGW's GCC -- either inside or outside of a function.

I'd use the preprocessor instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sint static int

int main(void)
{

    sint i = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Achieves the same result.

I'd imagine it's because "static int" isn't a type in the same way "volatile int" is.

Comment: Please don't do this. It will just make code more confusing than it has to be, `sint` won't be usable as a parameter type, and a function returning `sint` will have property that's probably not intended (internal linkage).

Answer (score -2):

typedef is syntactically same as a storage class. It is not a storage class.
typedef is similar to #define in effect, but typedef is interpreted by
Compiler while #define is by the preprocessor.
typedef can do textual substitutions that are beyond the capabilities of
the preprocessor.

Two purposes for using typedef
1. Portability
2. Better documentation