# How to use static with typedef?

Tags: c, static, typedef

Since `typedef` is a storage class in C, it cannot be used with `static` variables. For example , `typedef static int SI`, `SI a` would not work. So is there any other way of using static with typedef?

I already know that this can be done `#define SI static int`.

[Storage Classes in C](http://itee.uq.edu.au/~comp2303/Leslie_C_ref/C/CONCEPT/storage_class.html)

Comment: And the point of this is? Typing `static` really doesn't take that long, and it would end up confusing people trying to read your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674236/is-typedef-a-storage-class-specifier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

**typedef** doesn't declare an *instance* of a variable, it declares a *type* (type alias actually).

**static** is a qualifier you apply to an *instance*, not a *type*.

Answer (score 2):

No way. `static` specifies what the C Standard calls **storage duration**, which can be static, automatic, and allocated. A typedef only gives an existing type a new name. Since the storage duration is not a property of a type name, you can't include the duration with a typedef.

I'm not sure what your macro `#define static int SI` is intended to do. It looks fishy.

Comment: Abbreviated version of static int , so that I can directly declare static integers as `SI a`.

Comment: Then you have the macro backwards.

Comment: Nope , why would it be backwards

Comment: You have it backwards. *LOOK AT IT!* :-) It's `#define MACRONAME REPLACEMENT`, but you have the macro identifier and replacement text reversed because you apparently just cut and pasted it from the typedef. Bad programmer, no cookie for you today. :-)

Comment: there's no reason for struct not to be allowed to be static and bound to the current scope. This way, if you define a struct that only makes sense within your scope, it doesn't bleed outside this scope. Same goes for macros, it would be nice to have macros bound to current scope only, and I see no reason why it can't be a C feature. It would solve namespace clashing quite well. The only things that should be bound to global scope are core language features and domain specific extensions user wants visible in all their code.

Comment: typedef, include bleeding into all scopes is the reason we still need #ifndef #endif in all headers in C. You can't import something without contaminating  your whole project with definitions that are irrelevant in their scope. Include <stdio.h>, suddenly you are committed to all declarations, even the irrelevant ones in all of your program scope, and all programs using your library.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're misunderstanding `typedef`. `typedef` is used to introduce type aliases, i.e. new type names, and so only applies to type information. `static`, `auto`, etc. all apply to specific variables.

Comment: @cnicutar I see. `typedef` included with the storage classes is new to me, and seems odd.