# What is the scope, life of typedef, if typedef is a storage class?

Tags: c, typedef

I found that typedef has similar syntax as extern or static. Then what is the scope, life or the storage class of typedef?

Comment: `typedef` is a storage class specifier itself.

Comment: A typedef is just an alias - it's not "stored", so "storage class" and "life" are not applicable. Scope rules are the same as for anything else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674236/is-typedef-a-storage-class-specifier

Comment: The scope is like for any other declaration. There is no lifetime, as no object is defined.

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully, you'll notice when the standard says: `typedef` is called a "storage-class specifier", it uses quotation marks around **storage-class specifier** which implies that `typedef` is just syntactically a "storage-class specifier" for convenience.

So it's meaningless to talk about scope, type etc, of `typedef`.

> #### C99 §6.7.1 *Storage-class specifiers* Section 3
>
> The `typedef` specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class specifier’’ for syntactic convenience
> only; it is discussed in 6.7.7. The meanings of the various linkages and storage durations
> were discussed in 6.2.2 and 6.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` has the same scope as regular variables in C.
For a `typedef` in a header it will be visible from all C files that include it.
So, the scope of *typedefs* is the same as that of any other identifier .