# Compiler gives an error called Unknown type name

Tags: c, typedef

I have my following functions declared in stack.h file and when I compile my project an error Unknown type name is been shown for l_ifc_handle.

```
extern l_bool        l_ifc_init (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_wake_up (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_rx (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_tx (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern l_u16         l_ifc_read_status (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_aux (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern l_u16         l_sys_irq_disable (l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_sys_irq_restore (l_ifc_handle iii);
```

But my `l_ifc_handle` is structure variable in another file called driver.h and used in driver.c

```
typedef enum { 
   LI0
}l_ifc_handle;
```

This driver.h file includes my stack.h header file. But the `l_ifc_handle` is in my driver.h file.

If I use

```
typedef enum { 
   LI0
} extern l_ifc_handle;
```

then it gives an error called multiple storage classes. In which file should I place the above typedef?

Comment: Remove `extern` from the typedef. `extern` is used for variables, not for types.

Comment: As Klas said remove the `extern`, then be sure that the `typedef` is visible in all units where you refer to it, before the use. This because in standard language you cannot create forward reference for enums (while GCC allows it as custom extension).

Comment: Note that `l_ifc_handle` as shown is not a structure type — it is an enumeration type with a single enumerated value (and that's equivalent to `0`).  The rules on `enum` types are more stringent than those for structure types; you can't simply forward declare an enumeration — especially when the enumeration has no tag.

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef enum { 
   LI0
} extern l_ifc_handle;
```

> then it gives an error called multiple storage classes.

Storage specifier(`typedef, auto, static, register, extern`) are mutual exclusive, You can't use them in same declaration.

[Is typedef a storage-class-specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674236/is-typedef-a-storage-class-specifier)

Comment: @machine_1 [Grammatically it is.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `driver.h` into `stack.h`. Use forward declarations instead and include `driver.h` into you `.c` files when you need `LI0`.

```
extern l_bool        l_ifc_init (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_wake_up (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_rx (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_tx (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern l_u16         l_ifc_read_status (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_ifc_aux (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern l_u16         l_sys_irq_disable (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
extern void          l_sys_irq_restore (enum l_ifc_handle iii);
```

Comment: This is generally regarded as bad advice these days.  It is best for a header to be self-contained, idempotent and minimal.  Self-contained means you should be able to include the header without needing to work out what else to include beforehand. Idempotent means that the header can be included multiple times harmlessly.  Minimal means you can't remove anything from the file.  Amongst other things, you can't forward declare an `enum` type; the details must be known, so this `stack.h` should include `driver.h` in order to be self-contained.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Self-contained headers may increase compilation time. If you do not need those l_ifc_* functions, but need a couple of other functions from there, then compilation time without `driver.h` may be decreased.