# define variables in header instead of function (not global) in C

Tags: c, header, struct

I can't see any memory change in my .map file when I try to compare the two different codes.
Is there a "good practice" to follow here? Should I or shouldn't I put the variables in the header?
As a note, I can have multiple PIDUpdate() functions, I allready have two (if that makes any difference).

First example without variables in the header -> main.c

```
static int16_t PIDUpdate(int16_t target, int16_t feedback) // Valve
{
static float pTerm, iTerm, dTerm;
static float PID;
int16_t CurrentError;
static float LastError, SumError;
uint16_t tick;
static uint16_t elapsed;
float Kp = 0.1, Ki = 0.1, Kd = 0.1;

Kp = (float) pGain/10000.0;
Ki = (float) iGain/10000.0;
Kd = (float) dGain/10000.0;

....
if(elapsed = tick - timestamp, elapsed < TRACKING_PERIOD)
    goto leave;

timestamp = tick;

CurrentError = target - feedback;

pTerm = Kp * CurrentError;

// Calculate the Integral State with appropriate Limiting
....
iTerm = Ki * SumError;

dTerm = Kd * (LastError - CurrentError);

LastError = CurrentError;

PID = pTerm + iTerm + dTerm;

control = PID;
....
    leave:
return (control);
      }
```

The other example with variabels in header instead -> main.h

```
typedef struct PID
{
// PID parameters
uint16_t Kp; // pGain
uint16_t Ki; // iGain
uint16_t Kd; // dGain

// PID calculations
float pTerm;
float iTerm;
float dTerm;
float PID;

// Extra variabels
int16_t CurrentError;

// PID Time
uint16_t tick;

   }pid_object;

   typedef static struct staticPID
   {    
// Extra variabels
int16_t control;
float LastError;
float SumError;

// PID Time
uint16_t elapsed;
uint16_t timestamp;

    }StaticPid_object;
```

Now the main.c code togheter with above .h-file

```
static int16_t PIDUpdate(int16_t target, int16_t feedback) // Valve
{
pid_object _PID_t;
StaticPid_object _StatPID_t;

_PID_t.Kp = (float) pGain/10000.0;
_PID_t.Ki = (float) iGain/10000.0;
_PID_t.Kd = (float) dGain/10000.0;

if(_StatPID_t.elapsed = _PID_t.tick - _StatPID_t.timestamp, _StatPID_t.elapsed < TRACKING_PERIOD)
    goto leave;

_StatPID_t.timestamp = _PID_t.tick;

_PID_t.CurrentError = target - feedback;

_PID_t.pTerm = _PID_t.Kp * _PID_t.CurrentError;

// Calculate the Integral State with appropriate Limiting
....

_PID_t.iTerm = _PID_t.Ki * _StatPID_t.SumError;

_PID_t.dTerm = _PID_t.Kd * (_StatPID_t.LastError - _PID_t.CurrentError);

_StatPID_t.LastError = _PID_t.CurrentError;

_PID_t.PID = _PID_t.pTerm + _PID_t.iTerm + _PID_t.dTerm;

_StatPID_t.control = 255-_PID_t.PID; // Make it work oposite to Heater

     leave:
return (_StatPID_t.control);
     }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And why on earth are you using static local variables in the modern day? They were bad news 20 years ago. Now you just guarantee that you can only have one PID controller in your entire process.

Comment: BTW, the `_t` suffix is usually reserved for typedefs, not variable names.  And using the `_` prefix on variables local to a function is odd.  Most C coding standards use `_` to indicate a private (instead of public) function or global variable.

Comment: thanks tomlogic, Im in a learning process ;)

Comment: David, do you have a better suggestion of a reusable function that needs to remember it's values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where your code is — in `.h` or in `.c`, but if you include the header defining static variable in multiple files, you'll have different instance for each file. What matters here is if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're only defining data types in your main.h.  There aren't actually any variables there (even though it looks like it with that indentation).

I would say that including `static` in a typedef is crazy and there's no reason to do so.

Traditionally, in a program with foo.c, bar.c and baz.c, the file foo.h has datatypes, function declarations and `extern` versions of global variables that need to be seen outside of foo.c.  Likewise with bar.h and baz.h.

foo.h

> extern int some_global;

foo.c

> int some_global;

So `foo.c` supplies `some_global` when your program is linked, and `bar.c` and `baz.c` will know what it is.

Comment: thanks, that was educating. Why is it crazy to have static in a typedef? It makes my function to remember those variable values without making new static variables within the function (saving memory)?

Comment: @Christian: it's clearer to include the `static` in the declaration inside of your function.  `static Pid_Object _StatPID;`  Someone reading that function (maybe you in a few years) will immediately know that it's a static structure without having to go back to the definition of `StaticPid_object` to be sure.

Comment: Ah... so it's more convenient to go Pid_Object Static StatPID?

Comment: @Christian: The `static` has to be lower case, and I'd prefer to see it before the data type (that's how I'm used to seeing it in the C code I work with).  `static Pid_Object StatPID`

Comment: I'll remember that and try to use it, but why does the compiler accept both static Pid_Object StatPID and Pid_Object static StatPID?

Comment: @Christian: first, followup on not using `static` in a `typedef`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218435/why-typedef-can-not-be-used-with-static  And although the compiler accepts the storage specifier after the type, it's common practice to put it before the type specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `int foo;` is a definition which will allocate storage for the variable `foo` and `extern int foo;` is a declaration which says the storage of variable `foo` has already been given. You can put definitions in the header file, but you may get redefinition errors if you link several source files which include that header file. Usually we just put declarations in the header if needed, and define the variables in the corresponding source file. Other source files will see them during the linking phase.